# How to set state for DevExtreme React Grid When update on Grid

Tags: reactjs, devextreme

I have an DevExtreme React Grid with Batch Mode.I would like to know how to set value in "State" when I updated in Grid.Please check my below code and advise how to do this...

***Setting Initial State:-***

```
this.state = {
 GridState : []
};
```

***Load Existing Data in State:-***

```
componentDidMount() {
axios.get(ConfigItem[0].APIPath+'users/UserRights/2')
.then(res => {
  console.log(res.data.data);
 this.setState({GridState:res.data.data});
})  

}
```

***Get the Grid State Data when clicking on submit button :-***

```
onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.dataGrid.instance.saveEditData();
  console.log(this.state.GridState); // Here I am getting existing data only but I need to get updated data also.
}
```

***HTML Render:-***

```
    <div id="data-grid-demo">
    <DataGrid
      dataSource={this.state.GridState}
      ref={ref => this.dataGrid = ref}
      keyExpr="UserAccessId"
      showBorders={true}
      onToolbarPreparing={this.onToolbarPreparing}
    >
      <Paging enabled={false} />
      <Editing
        mode="batch"
        allowUpdating={true}
        selectTextOnEditStart={true}
        startEditAction='click' />
      <Column dataField="UserAccessId" visible={false} />
      <Column dataField="MenuId" visible={false}  />
      <Column dataField="Menu" width={100} />
      <Column dataField="SubMenu" width={170} />
      <Column dataField="ViewAccess" caption="ViewAccess" dataType="boolean" width={150} >
        <CheckBox defaultValue={false} />
      </Column>
      <Column dataField="ZohoParameter"  />
      <Column dataField="Remarks"  />

    </DataGrid>


  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [onRowUpdated](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#onRowUpdated) prop of the DataGrid and from the data field of the object parameter get a changed row.

Comment: The following [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/batch-editing-devextreme-data-grid-zjomp) demonstrates this.

Comment: thanks for reply,I have checked above link,the example works fine in sandbox but in my code why "onRowUpdated" event is not fire ???

Comment: sorry please ignore my above problem... 
I have solved my problem, Actually I have assigned wrong key field in grid